Refreshing data only after every time interval from live master sheet
I have a master sheet that receives live data. I want to link that data to another sheet, which I have already done.
The data on the master sheet refreshes instantaneously (which is almost every second), however, I want the data in my sheet to refresh only after every 1 minute (for example). Can somebody please point me in the direction I should look to achieve this?

You'll probably need VBA (which is probably already implemented based on the master sheet being constantly updated), but the answer will really depend on what that link to the other sheet is. For example, if formulas maybe a recalc would do it, if a table, then a refresh might be the answer. There could be others.
